PHP Project, Graphql queries returning null value
I am working on a PHP and React.js project using Mysql and graphql in backend. Currently I am trying to run some queries on the server but they return errors and nulls like this :
{
  "errors": [
     {
      "message": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 2
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "getCategory"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "getCategory": null
  }
}

Even though the data is present and accessible with Mysql server.
Here's my schema.php and CategoryResolver :
<?php

namespace Backend\GraphQL\Schemas;
namespace Backend\GraphQL\Resolvers;

use Backend\Classes\Category;
use Exception;

class CategoryResolver
{
    public function getAllCategories()
    {
        try {
            $categories = Category::all();
            $transformedCategories = [];

            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                $products = $category->products()->get();
                $transformedCategory = [
                    'id' => $category->id,
                    'name' => $category->name,
                    'description' => $category->description,
                    'products' => $products->toArray(),
                ];
                $transformedCategories[] = $transformedCategory;
            }

            return $transformedCategories;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            error_log($e->getMessage());
            throw new Exception('Failed to fetch categories');
        }
    }

    public function getCategory($args)
    {
        try {
            $categoryId = $args['id'];
            $category = Category::findOrFail($categoryId);
            $products = $category->products()->get();

            $transformedCategory = [
                'id' => $category->id,
                'name' => $category->name,
                'description' => $category->description,
                'products' => $products->toArray(),
            ];

            return $transformedCategory;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            error_log($e->getMessage());
            throw new Exception('Failed to fetch category');
        }
    }
}

<?php

namespace Backend\GraphQL\Resolvers;

use Backend\Classes\Category;
use Exception;

class CategoryResolver
{
    public function getAllCategories()
    {
        try {
            $categories = Category::all();
            $transformedCategories = [];

            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                $products = $category->products()->get();
                $transformedCategory = [
                    'id' => $category->id,
                    'name' => $category->name,
                    'description' => $category->description,
                    'products' => $products->toArray(),
                ];
                $transformedCategories[] = $transformedCategory;
            }

            return $transformedCategories;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            error_log($e->getMessage());
            throw new Exception('Failed to fetch categories');
        }
    }

    public function getCategory($args)
    {
        try {
            $categoryId = $args['id'];
            $category = Category::findOrFail($categoryId);
            $products = $category->products()->get();

            $transformedCategory = [
                'id' => $category->id,
                'name' => $category->name,
                'description' => $category->description,
                'products' => $products->toArray(),
            ];

            return $transformedCategory;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            error_log($e->getMessage());
            throw new Exception('Failed to fetch category');
        }
    }
}


I tried changing the query to something like
query { getAllProducts { id name } }
but also getting errors
{ "data": { "getAllProducts": null } }
the Data is stored in a Data.json file in the root directory and is imported through this file :
<?php

// Read the JSON file
$jsonString = file_get_contents('data.json');

// Decode the JSON
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);

// Access Categories and Products
$categories = $data['categories'] ?? [];
$products = $data['products'] ?? [];

// Database Connection
// Replace DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_USER, and DB_PASSWORD with your database credentials
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=8000;dbname=scandiweb;charset=utf8mb4', 'root', '0120852868');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

try {
    // Insert Categories into Database
    $pdo->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categories (
        id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    )");

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO categories (name) VALUES (:name)");
        $stmt->execute(['name' => $category['name']]);
        
        // Output a success message for each inserted category
        echo "Category '{$category['name']}' inserted successfully.<br>";
    }

    // Insert Products into Database
    $pdo->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products (
        id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        in_stock BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
        description TEXT,
        category VARCHAR(255),
        brand VARCHAR(255)
    )");

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO products (name, in_stock, description, category, brand) VALUES (:name, :in_stock, :description, :category, :brand)");
        $stmt->execute([
            'name' => $product['name'],
            'in_stock' => $product['inStock'] ? 1 : 0,
            'description' => $product['description'],
            'category' => $product['category'],
            'brand' => $product['brand']
        ]);
    }

    echo "Data imported successfully.";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    // If an error occurs during any part of the import process, catch the exception and output the error message
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>

